# laravel double post submit with database prevention

Tags: php, laravel, validation, locking, lumen

In my lumen application I have a form where users need to enter their phone, that I verify. Phone must be unique for each user, and an SMS is sent with a secret code user must enter to validate the number.

I added a validation rule `'phone' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($except)]` to check if the phone is unique, and if it passes I push a job that handles SMS sending, and save the new phone.

The problem is that if a user submits the form twice (clicks submit button on client application fast, I don't have control of it), the validation rule passes for BOTH requests, it creates 2 jobs that send 2 sms messages.

When debugging the problem further I found the same thing happens on my registration action, that validates unique email rule. If form is submited two times fast, validation passes, but one of the requests receives database level error about unique constraint violation.

How do I properly "lock" users to prevent concurrent submits that bypass validation?

Comment: Put a unique constraint on the database table and then use the success of an INSERT to determine if the given value was appropriately unique.

Comment: How is the form submitted? If Ajax then you could have a beforesubmit function which disables the button on first click and reenable it in the complete function. Otherwise you could put a write lock on the database table which will queue the database query from the second process until the lock is released by the first

Comment: While this will work as a workaround if I remove `->ignore($except)` from my rule, It will still cause an error thrown by the application. And it will not prevent double posts where database update is done strictly AFTER the external service call.

Comment: Frontend based workaround (like js, button disabling) will only create problems for the future, because multiple clients will be written for the lumen app, and each one will have to not forget doing it. Need a solution, not a workaround.